# JPA batch inserts with @Id without any generation strategy

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I am querying an API and persisting the data into db2 database using JPARepository. Since I have more than 150,000 records it is taking some time when using saveAll() simply. So, to enable batch inserts I am using following in my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc_batch_size=500
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.batch_versioned_data=true
```

Despite this I can see in the debug logs that no batches are running **0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches**;

Upon browsing I found out that issue might be due to @Id generation strategy as hibernate disables batching for Identity generation but in my case I don't need any @Id generator, my PK is 4 fields that is there in the data class from the API upstream. The model class looks like this

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLES", schema = "TEST")
@IdClass(AppleResponseId.class)
public class AppleResponse {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SRC_SEQ")
    private String seq;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SRC_SYSTEM")
    private String system;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    private Double amount;
```

and my repository class is simply

```
@Repository
public interface AppleRepository extends JpaRepository<AppleResponse , AppleResponseId> {
}
```